# "Du läufst ins Haus"

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

I was doing my Duolingo course, and I met the following sentence

> Du läufst ins Haus

Now this sentence is confusing me. This should be the same as

> Du läufst in das Haus

But in that case, wouldnt that mean that *Haus* is written in nominative form? That does not seem to make any sense.

Even worse is the translation offered:

> You walk home

This is a sentence I would have written as

> Du läufst nach Hause

Can someone please explain me this sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, *in das Haus* is accusative, but you will see no difference for neuter nouns.

*Nach Hause* is a fixed phrase, and no longer directly coupled to *Haus*. So your translation is also fine.

Comment: The -e suffix in *nach Hause* is an old dative -e which became almost extinct in German, but this phrase preserved it.

Comment: I did not know that "lauf in" used accusative! Thanks!

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent: This is not restricted to *laufen* but shared among all specifications of a target.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent you should not generalise in this case: one could also say _Ich laufe in dem Haus_ - which would use _laufen in_ + Dativ and means something like _I run/walk inside the house_

Comment: Crap... Now that is difficult to differentiate now...

Answer (score 4):

Both the phrases

> Du läufst nach Hause

and

> Du läufst ins Haus (= Du läufst in das Haus)

are grammatically correct, but their meaning differs.

The first one means
literally "you run home", but it may also mean "you walk home (instead of using the car or the bus)".

The second phrase means "you run into the house (e.g., because you were sitting in the garden and suddenly noticed smoke from the kitchen window)".

Comment: We had a discussion here about the meaning of *laufen* some weeks ago. It's basically in Austria where *laufen* means to run; in most other regions, laufen means to walk or to go. So I would translate the second sentence as "you go into the house". Apart of that I agree with your explanation.

Comment: What about the case? "in das Haus" is nominative, but it looks to me as if it should be dative

Comment: @scienceponder I'm from Northrhine-Westphalia. For me, "laufen" either means (1) "run (as opposed to walking slowly)" or (2) "walk (as opposed to driving or using other means of transportation)." But in the second sentence, meaning (2) doesn't make sense (most people can't drive into their living room), so (1) is the only possible interpretation. Typically, I'd say "ich gehe ins Haus"; "laufen" really stresses the speed in this context.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent "Das Haus" is accusative here. "In" can be used either with dative to denote a location, or with accusative to denote a direction.

Comment: @uwe Acknowledged. The point, that it only means "walk" when it obviously opposes driving would have been interesting in the other discussion we had some weeks before.